# Javascript sort an array of arrays by child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How can I sort an array of arrays by the second element which is also an array that contains only one element?

For example, the following array

```
array = [
    ["text", ["bcc"], [2]],
    ["text", ["cdd"], [3]],
    ["text", ["aff"], [1]],
    ["text", ["zaa"], [5]],
    ["text", ["d11"], [4]]
];
```

Should be sorted as follows:

```
sorted_array = [
    ["text", ["aff"], [1]],
    ["text", ["bcc"], [2]],
    ["text", ["cdd"], [3]],
    ["text", ["d11"], [4]],
    ["text", ["zaa"], [5]]
];
```

Comment: I see 3 level of arrays here. if it is single value why child 'bcc' is in array. it is possible it may have more values?

Comment: would you like to sort with `['bcc']` or with the number [2]?

Comment: @NinaScholz I need the array to be sorted in alphabetical order depending on the second element from each array

Comment: arrays are zero based, what is your second element?

Comment: `['bcc']` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.sort()` method which accepts a `callback` function.

Also, you have to use `.localeCompare` method in order to compare two `strings`.

```js
array = [
    ["text", ["bcc"], [1]],
    ["text", ["cdd"], [1]],
    ["text", ["aff"], [1]],
    ["text", ["zaa"], [1]],
    ["text", ["d11"], [1]]
];
var sortedArray=array.sort(callback);
function callback(a,b){
  return a[1][0].localeCompare(b[1][0]);
}
console.log(sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort()` method like this.

```js
var array = [
    ["text", ["bcc"], [1]],
    ["text", ["cdd"], [1]],
    ["text", ["aff"], [1]],
    ["text", ["zaa"], [1]],
    ["text", ["d11"], [1]]
];

var result = array.sort((a, b) => a[1][0].localeCompare(b[1][0]))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: what  if you wanna sort based on all the element of the array, is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the nested elements with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
var array = [["text", ["bcc"], [2]], ["text", ["cdd"], [3]], ["text", ["aff"], [1]], ["text", ["zaa"], [5]], ["text", ["d11"], [4]]];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1][0].localeCompare(b[1][0]);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by passing compared child level array in array sort function

```
array = [
    ["text", ["bcc"], [1]],
    ["text", ["cdd"], [1]],
    ["text", ["aff"], [1]],
    ["text", ["zaa"], [1]],
    ["text", ["d11"], [1]]
];

function Comparator(a, b) {
   if (a[1] < b[1]) return -1;
   if (a[1] > b[1]) return 1;
   return 0;
}

array = array.sort(Comparator);
console.log(array);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

(Only for modern JavaScript engines)

```
array.sort(([,[a]], [,[b]]) => a.localeCompare(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) { 
    if (a[1][0] > b[1][0])
        return 1;
    else if (a[1][0] < b[1][0])
        return -1;
    return 0; 
});
```